# Keyboard shortcut for moving to the end of a multiline statement in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Using the IntelliJ code editor for Java, is there a keyboard shortcut to move the insertion point past the end of the last line of a multi-line statement?

Example:

```java
Map < String, Integer > map =
        Map.of(
                "Alice" , 42 ,⁁    ← Move insertion point (caret, ⁁) from here…
                "Bob" , 2 ,
                "Carol" , 7
        );⁁                        ← … to here.
```

Comment: You an try using ⇧⌘⏎ (macOS), Ctrl+Shift+Enter (Windows/Linux)

Comment: Very good question! I was also looking solution to this requirement. The solution provided by @EgorKlepikov should work for you. It moves the cursor to a new line after `;` and this is what I was looking for.